# Best way to filter ListView with drop down form in Django

Tags: django, listview, filter

I'm trying to filter a ListView based on Users, using a drop down form.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name="Post Author")
```

views.py

```
class PostList(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(PostList, self).get_queryset()

        author_filter = self.request.GET.get('author')
        if author_filter:
            result = Post.objects.filter(Q(author__icontains=author_filter))
        return result
```

post_list.html

```
<form action="" method="get">
          <select name="author" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option selected="selected" disabled>Select an author</option>
            {% all_author as authors %}
            {% for author in authors %}
            <option value="{{ author }}">{{ author }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </form>
```

I am using a custom template tag to render `all_authors` and this works fine. When selecting an author, in the urls I can see something is passed (/?author=xxx), but the list is not filtered.

**EDIT**

Based on andi's suggestion I made it work this way using django filters. But for some reason `fields = ['field_name',]` in filters.py is not taken into account, so I'm selecting the fields individually in the template.

views.py

```
class PostList(FilterView):
    model = Post
    filter_class = PostFilter
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'directory/post_list.html'
```

filters.py

```
class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['author',]
```

post_list.html

```
<form action="" method="get">
            {{ filter.form.author }}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

**EDIT 2**

I've found out why the selected fields were not passed correctly, needed to use in views `filterset_class =` instead of `filter_class =`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ohh, it is really oldschool, error prone and time consuming way of doing the things.

Please give a try to `django-filter` library. And create working fine filters with minimum amount of effort! This allows creating very robust filtering strategies while maintaining clean code.

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html#

below fast draft:

the filter:

```
import django_filters

class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['author']
```

the view:

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView
from somwhere.in.your.project.filtersets import PostFilter

class PostList(FilterView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    filter_class = PostFilter
```

in template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
        {{ obj.name }} - ${{ obj.price }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @robtus88 I providede example of PostList(FilterView) just add template_name = 'path/to/your/template.html'

Comment: I see, now it works. The only problems I have now are that all fields of my model are displayed in filters (I would like to select only some), and I don't see how I can style the filters (layout). Do you know how to tackle these 2 points?

Comment: Limit it via fields = ('field_nam', ) in filterset definition

Comment: Small mistake in the View definition: it seems like you need to set `filterset_class` instead of `filter_class` ([original code](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/master/django_filters/views.py#L37)). Other than that, this was very helpful.

Comment: Does not work if you using ListView's paginator

Comment: @run_the_race `If you want to access the filtered objects in your views, for example if you want to paginate them, you can do that. They are in f.qs`  https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html?highlight=pagination#the-view

Answer (score 0):

In your form, try changing this:

```
<option value="{{ author }}">{{ author }}</option>
```

to this:

```
<option value="{{ author.pk }}">{{ author }}</option>
```

Then, in your view:

```
if author_filter:
    result = Post.objects.filter(author_id=int(auth_filter))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change it, when I select an author the list doesn't update, I tried to print `author_filter` but nothing shows up, so I guess the problem is earlier in the code

Comment: the variable in the url is updated, but still nothing happening with the view. `author_filter ` is still showing nothing so I would say either `self.request.GET.get('author')` has a problem, or my html, but I cannot see which one. If you know of an other way to do this I'm all ears :)