# How to append two separate forms to the end of a url in Django

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create a django web app, and I'm running into an issue with forms. I have a simple `index.html` set up that has two separate regular html forms on the page. One for filtering and the other for sorting. Currently, I can get either filtering, or sorting to work, but not both at the same time. I think this is because I'm missing a fundamental understanding of django somewhere. Yes, I've done the tutorials.

I've attempted manually appending the URL to my url config, but that didn't work as intended.

```html
<form action="" method="get">
    {% for filter in view.all_filters %}
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="{{ filter }}">
            {{ filter }}
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Apply Filters">
</form>
```

```html
<form action="." method="get">
    <label>
        Sort By
        <select name="order_by">
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="description">Description</option>
            <option value="cvssBaseScore">Cvss Base Score</option>
            <option value="cvssV3BaseScore">Cvss V3 Base Score</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like the url to be able to append something like `?filters=one&filters=two&order_by=name` or something as such.

Comment: You don't understand how HTML forms work. Just use one <form> only so that when it's submitted, all the the input values contained in the form are appended to the url.

Comment: That makes sense and is the change I used, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this. I'm fairly new to front-end so this is a bit of a catch up for me, so sorry if the question seems intentionally stupid.

Comment: No need to apologise, you have to start somewhere :-) No, there isn't a better way. A <form> element encapsulates all data that it submits, if you put two separate forms in your HTML page, then you intentionally want only one of the forms to be submitted with its data. A typical example for two forms would be a page where you have a login form and a 'enter your details' form, so users can choose whether to login or not when making purchase.

Comment: Note that Django `Form`s don't have to map 1-to-1 to HTML <form>s. You could have a Django view that renders two Django forms in a template, but in the HTML have only one <form> to submit both. This would be the case if you want to update two different models at the same time.

Comment: That makes sense. Django seems to automate a lot of things that I only understand on the fringe. I think this sufficiently answers my question, so I should mark this as answered. Thanks Dirk!

Comment: Is your original purpose filtering and sorting in a list view? If yes, there are more standard ways of doing that

Comment: I mean, you are probably looking for something like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350362/django-listview-form-to-filter-and-sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not really related to Django but rather to how HTML forms work:

A `<form>` element encapsulates all the data (`<input>`s) that it submits, so if you put two separate forms in your HTML page, then you intentionally want only one of the forms to be submitted with its data.

Just put both your inputs (the filter and the order_by inputs) inside the same `<form>` element so that both are submitted when either of the submit buttons is clicked.