# django - CBV - pass in multiple values from url

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am utterly confused and mortified by CBVs, seeking for help.

So I've designed the model structure and decided the url patterns as following, **but simply can't write a valid CBV to facilitate the urls**:

models.py

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    '''Category for men's and women's items'''
    men = models.BooleanField()
    women = models.BooleanField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Men's " + self.name) if self.men else ("Women's " + self.name)


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    '''Sub-category for the categories (not mandatory)'''
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'Sub-category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sub-categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Men's " + self.name) if self.category.men else ("Women's " + self.name)


class Item(models.Model):
    '''Each item represents a product'''
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    discount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-uploaded_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def discounted_price(self):
        '''to calculate the price after discount'''
        return int(self.price * (100 - self.discount) * 0.01)


class ItemImage(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='itemimages', null=True, blank=True)
```

urls.py

```py
app_name = 'boutique'
urlpatterns = [
    # show index page
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # show categories of products for men or women
    path('<slug:gender>/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='show-all'),

    # show a specific category for men or women
    path('<slug:gender>/cat_<int:category_pk>/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='category'),

    # show a specific subcategory under a specific category for men or women
    path('<slug:gender>/cat_<int:category_pk>/subcat_<int:subcategory_pk>/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='subcategory'),

    # show a specific item
    path('item_<int:item_pk>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item'),
]
```

views.py

```py
class IndexView(ListView):
    '''landing page'''
    model = Category
    template_name = 'boutique/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'


class ItemListView(ListView):
    '''display a list of items'''
    # model = Category ??? what's the point of declaring model when get_context_data() ???
    template_name = 'boutique/items.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'
    paginate_by = 12

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=self.kwargs.get('category_pk'))
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all() # for rendering nav bar data
        return context

class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    '''display an individual item'''
    # model = Item
    template_name = 'boutique/item.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs['item_pk'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

items.html

```html
<a href="{% url 'boutique:show-all' 'women' %}> link to categories of product for women </a>
<a href="{% url 'boutique:category' 'women' category.pk %}> link to a cat for women </a>
<a href="{% url 'boutique:subcategory' 'women' category.pk subcategory.pk %}> link to a subcat under a specific cat for women </a>
```

Essentially, as you can see, I'd like the `ItemListView` to render multiple url paths depending on what value passed into the CBV... I can do it (pass multiple values) in a FBV, however, utterly confused by the mechanism of the CBVs...

So if anyone could write an example `ItemListView` and according anchor url template tags (if mine are incorrect), it would be tremendulent!!! Thanks!!!

## EDIT 1

```py
class ItemListView(ListView):
    '''display a list of items'''
    model = Item
    template_name = 'boutique/items.html'
    # paginate_by = 12

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get original queryset: Item.objects.all()
        qs = super().get_queryset()

        # filter items: men/women
        if self.kwargs['gender'] == 'women':
            qs = qs.filter(category__women=True)
        elif self.kwargs['gender'] == 'men':
            qs = qs.filter(category__men=True)

        if self.kwargs.get('category_pk'):
            qs = qs.filter(category=self.kwargs.get('category_pk'))
            if self.kwargs.get('subcategory_pk'):
                qs = qs.filter(subcategory=self.kwargs.get('subcategory_pk'))

        # print(qs)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # add categories for navbar link texts
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()

        if self.kwargs.get('gender') == 'women':
            context['category_shown'] = Category.objects.filter(women=True)
        if self.kwargs.get('gender') == 'men':
            context['category_shown'] = Category.objects.filter(men=True)

        if self.kwargs.get('category_pk'):
            context['category_shown']=get_object_or_404(Category, pk=self.kwargs.get('category_pk'))
            if self.kwargs.get('subcategory_pk'):
                context['subcategory_shown']=get_object_or_404(SubCategory, pk=self.kwargs.get('subcategory_pk'))

        # print(context)
        return context
```

After FiddleStix' answer (I haven't gone thu bluegrounds thread yet), I tried and managed to make everything work except `ItemDetailView`.

The urls are working fine and the filtering of `get_queryset` function is working fine, however,

**Question 1**: I wonder this might not be DRY enough?! Nevertheless, it's working. so thanks!! But could it be dryer??

**Question 2**: when `ItemDetailView` runs, the urls appear to be correct, however, the page redirect to a page rendering all items from all categories...

```py
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    '''display an individual item'''
    # model = Item
    template_name = 'boutique/item.html'

    def get_object(self):
        print(get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs.get('item_pk')))
        return get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs.get('item_pk'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # add categories for navbar link texts
        # context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        print(context)
        return context
```

Neither is the object nor the context being printed out... and it doesn't prompt any error, either. I must have made a silly mistake somewhere!!

---

## Answer to Question 2:

view.py

```py
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    '''display an individual item'''
    model = Item
    template_name = 'boutique/item.html'
```

#### The DetailView class should be simple if no customisation is needed, the problem is in the `urlpatterns`:

url.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('item_<int:pk>', view.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item'),
]
```

- Always use `<pk>` as the value passed in DetailView as it's the default. I used `item_<int:item_pk>` as the path url. That's why I had to use `get_object()` to manually get the item object (to override the default `get_object()`). As @bluegrounds answer suggests that the reason Class-based Views work well is they save time, for the default functions they possess.
- If you wish to use `item_<int:item_pk>`, CBV offers the flexibility as well: simply override `pk_url_kwargs = 'item_pk'` in the View class - Feel free to check [my other question: DetailView - `get_object` function confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113746/django-detailview-get-object-function-confusion/60113771#60113771) for clarification. @neverwalkaloner 's answer is very straightforward.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  I assume that your urls.py is working and you can go to /women/1/ or /women/1/3 to get a page to display.  However, I think you then want to access the "women", "1" and "3" within the CBV so that you can pass them back to the template to render more URLs?  If so, you can do `gender = self.kwargs['gender']` in your `get_context_data()`.  The same goes for category_pk and subcategory_pk.

Comment: @FiddleStix Sorry I should have made it clearer: `ImproperlyConfigured at /women/
ItemListView is missing a QuerySet. Define ItemListView.model, ItemListView.queryset, or override ItemListView.get_queryset().` None of the urls is working except for index...

Comment: To be precise, I do not know how a <slug> in url.py gets passed into the ItemListView, let alone 3 <slug>s when displaying a subcategory list view. It's not like a FBV, everything is passed in by the form of parameters when the function is defined. However, how can a CBV catch 3 values from url baffles me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first things first, CBVs...

They work by having "default" behaviours built into each one of them. For the ListView class, take this example view:

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article
```

along with an example urlpattern:

```
path('all-articles/', ArticleListView.as_view())
```

and that's it. This is all that is essential for a ListView to work. This `ArticleListView` view would look for a template called `article_list.html` and in it you can use the context variable `object_list` to access all the Article objects that the class gets for you without you having to write the QuerySet explicitly.

Of course you can change these values, and customize the QuerySet, and do all kinds of things, but for that you'll have to study the docs. I personally find [ccbv](https://ccbv.co.uk/) much easier to read than the docs. So for example you can see in [ccbv's page](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) about ListViews that the `context_object_name = None` which defaults to `object_list`, as mentioned above. You can change that to, for example `context_object_name = 'my_articles'`. You could also set the `template_name = 'my_articles.html'` and that will override the default template name pattern of <*model*>_list.html.

Now, about your code,

If you're sure that you want your URL structure to stay like it is, you could have your class view as follows to get the functionality you need:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'boutique/items.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'
    paginate_by = 12

    def get_queryset(self):
        # This method should return a queryset that represents the items to be listed in the view.
        # I think you intend on listing categories in your view, in which case consider changing the view's name to CategoryListView. Just sayin'...
        # An instance of this view has a dictionary called `kwargs` that has the url parameters, so you can do the following:

        # You need some null assertions here because of the way you've setup your URLs
        qs = Categories.objects.filter(men=self.kwargs['gender'], pk=self.kwargs['category_pk'])
        return qs
```

As you can see, we didn't set many things in this class view for it to work. Namely, we didn't set the `model` variable as we did previously. That's because we wouldn't need it. The part that uses that variable was in the default `get_queryset()` method and we've overridden that method. See CCBV for more info on the default implementation of `get_queryset()`.

Now the template will be supplied with the objects from `get_queryset()`, under the name `categories`, because that's what we set `context_object_name`'s value to be.

NOTE: The variable `model` is used in other places other than `get_queryset()` such as the default `template_name`. The default template name is derived from the model name and the `template_name_suffix`. So if you don't set the `model` variable, make sure to set the `template_name` manually.

I'm not sure about your application's logic but I think you should change the `Category` model to have only one Boolean field that denotes gender. For example men if it is True and women if it's False. That way a category can't be for both men and women at the same time (unless that is something you need), and it also can't be for neither, because currently you can have a category be false for the both gender fields, which doesn't really make sense.

I would actually suggest a completely different solution that involves CHOICES, as such:

```
gender = models.IntegerField(null=False, CHOICES=[(1,'Men'), (2,'Women'), (3,'Other'), (4,'Unisex')], default=3)
```

This would store a number in the database that denotes the gender, and in your app you'll only see the correlating string (gender) to that number.

---

I have not tried this code on my machine so I might have missed a few things, but I hope I clarified the overall workings of CBVs.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The answer is very thorough. And thanks for introducing CCBV to me. It helped a lot! @bluegrounds

Comment: @DL8, My pleasure. As for your updated 2nd question, have you fixed that? I believe it's something wrong in urls.py because a DetailView would not be able to send a list of items to the template, unless you explicitly mess around with `get_context_data()`

Comment: also, I've found that printing to the console is not a very effective way to debug django apps. I would suggest an IDE like pyCharm, or "Werkzeug" if you don't want to use an IDE.

Comment: Yes! I have fixed the problem and appended the answer above. As you said, it's the problem in `urlpatterns`.    I'm using Visual Studio and I am indeed overwhelmed by the plugins... Would you recommend 'Werkzeug' over an IDE?

Comment: No Visual Studio is pretty good. I haven't used it for developing python apps but I know it's a good IDE. Look into using breakpoints. I don't think you need to configure anything to use them.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you main question, your `ItemList` should set `model=models.Item`, as alluded to in the error message, because it is meant to be a list of items.

I would set up your urls.py so that /items/ or /item_list/ goes to ItemListView.as_view().  If you then want to filter your list of items, I would not do it by changing the URL to /items/women/.  Instead, I would use a URL query string like /items/?gender=women.  How to do that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350362/django-listview-form-to-filter-and-sort) but basically:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "item_list.html"
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_val = self.request.GET.get('gender', 'some_default')

        queryset = Item.objects.filter(
            ...  # You'll have to work this bit out
        )
        return queryset 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['gender'] = self.request.GET.get('gender', 'some_default')
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely answer! after fiddling for a couple of hours I managed to make it work, code appended above, I wonder if it could be DRYer? I'd appreciate some feedback cheers~