# Django - DetailView - `get_object` function confusion

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, detailview

I'm new to CBV. Not sure why this isn't working...

views.py

```py
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    '''display an individual item'''
    model = Item
    template_name = 'boutique/item.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'

    # With model specified, following code would be redundant, wouldn't it?? However...
    # def get_object(self):
        # return get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs.get('item_pk'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # add categories for navbar link texts
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()

        print('\ncontext= ', context, '\n')
        return context
```

### `AttributeError at /item_8/ Generic detail view ItemDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

And the context isn't being printed out.

---

If I add `get_object` to the code, it's working fine:

```py
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    '''display an individual item'''
    # model = Item
    template_name = 'boutique/item.html'
    # context_object_name = 'item'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs.get('item_pk'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # add categories for navbar link texts
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()

        print('\ncontext= ', context, '\n')
        return context
```

---

However, if I changed `get_object` function to:

```py
    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        obj = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=self.kwargs.get('item_pk'))
        # obj = obj.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('item_pk')) # doesn't work, same error
        # obj = obj.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('item_pk')) # doesn't work, same error

        return obj
```

### `ImproperlyConfigured at /item_8/ ItemDetailView is missing a QuerySet. Define ItemDetailView.model, ItemDetailView.queryset, or override ItemDetailView.get_queryset().`

***I'm confused... DetailView should work without having to define `get_object` at all no??***

---

### additional files:

url.py

```py
app_name = 'boutique'
urlpatterns = [
    # show index page
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # show a specific item
    path('item_<int:item_pk>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item'),

    # show categories of products for men or women
    path('<slug:gender>/', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='show-all'),

    # show a specific category for men or women
    path('<slug:gender>/cat_<int:category_pk>/', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category'),

    # show a specific subcategory under a specific category for men or women
    path('<slug:gender>/cat_<int:category_pk>/subcat_<int:subcategory_pk>/', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='subcategory'),

]
```

models.py

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    '''Each item represents a product'''
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    discount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    uploaded_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-uploaded_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def discounted_price(self):
        '''to calculate the price after discount'''
        return int(self.price * (100 - self.discount) * 0.01)

    def get_item_url(self):
        return reverse('boutique:item', kwargs={'item_pk': self.pk})
```

item.html

```html
<!-- display each item in its own box -->
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-1 px-sm-2 d-flex flex-column">

    <!-- image anchor -->
    <a href="{{ item.get_item_url }}">
        <img class="rounded-sm" src="{{item.itemimage_set.first.image.url}}" width="100%"
    alt=""></a>
    <!-- /image anchor -->

    <!-- item price tag -->
    <div class="text-left p-1 mt-auto" style="font-size: 16px;">
        <div class="font-weight-light pt-2">
            <a href="{{ item.get_item_url }}" class="text-dark mb-1">{{item}}</a>
        </div>

        <div class="font-weight-lighter">
            {% if item.discount %}

            <p>
                <strike class="text-muted">&#8381;&nbsp;{{item.price}}</strike>
                <b class="text-danger">&#8381;&nbsp;{{item.discounted_price}}</b>
                <small class="text-danger">(-{{item.discount}}%)</small>
            </p>

            {% else %}
            <p>&#8381;&nbsp;{{item.price}}</p>

            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /item price tag -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is correct, you don't need to define `get_object()` explicitly but you should use `pk` argument instead of `item_pk` in url path when using details CBV:

```
path('item_<int:pk>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item'),
```

Since by default `get_object()` method using `self.kwargs["pk"]` to search object.

If you still want to use `item_pk` you need to specify in in view using [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg):

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    pk_url_kwarg = 'item_pk'
```

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#performing-extra-work):

> The URLconf here uses the named group pk - this name is the default
>   name that DetailView uses to find the value of the primary key used to
>   filter the queryset.
>
> If you want to call the group something else, you can set pk_url_kwarg
>   on the view. More details can be found in the reference for DetailView