# Sorting data / refresh page with new query - Django5 ListView

Tags: python, django

I am trying to perform a query on the same page using Django. After selecting data from the dropdown and clicking the button, the information should be filtered accordingly.

However, I couldn't find a solution to get the data after selecting from my dropdown and will refresh the page using Django.

[image]

Is this possible?

Here's my views.py

```
class DocListView(ListView):
model = Document
template_name = 'docs/documents.html'
paginate_by = 5
context_object_name = 'doc_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Document.objects.all()
```

Comment: See thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350362/django-listview-form-to-filter-and-sort or check out the the [django-filters package](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).